# App is faster from expo than local. Is that normal?

Tags: performance, react-native, expo

**Environment**

react: 16.3.1
react-native: 0.55.2
node: 8.2.1
npm: 6.1.0
expo: 27.0.1

**Description**

The app runs well, but, running from local, it goes slow, but running from expor online, goes faster. Is that normal?

**Steps to Reproduce**

It can be reproduce from this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@gersonmontenegro/select-favorite-example-with-drawer)

**Expected Behavior**

Get a well user experience running from local.

**Actual Behavior**

Application goes so slow running from local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you call "expo online" so I will guess it's your published app.

In developement mode, a lot of invisible debug is present in the app, it will help you get error in console, hot reloading ect.

In the console there's a line like : `__DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF`

In exp or expo XDE, there's an option to disable developement mode

Once you publish your app, all the optimizations are ON, so your app run smoother.

Comment: thanks for explanation, and yes, you were well guessing.